# What is the average age of guests reviewed by each host?

Tags: sql

these are the two data tables im working from
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU2C3.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6W61.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
  A.from_user, 
  sum(B.age) / sum(1.0) as average_age,
from A 
inner join B on A.to_user = B.guest_id
where from_type = 'host' and to_type='guest'
group by A.from_user
```